# Run VSCode's Developer: Reload Window command from the Terminal (bat file)

Tags: visual-studio-code, batch-file

I currently have a swagger-codegen script which generates axios wrappers for my REST API and whenever I run the script I get missing file errors everywhere until I restart Visual Studio Code or run the `Developer: Reload Window` command from the command palette. How can I run this command from my bat file?

Comment: how do you expect the bat file to continue after the reload, and you cant execute VSC commands from a terminal shell, you can create a keybind that executes the command and insert the batch command in the terminal

Comment: The command would be the last one of the bat file